# Handling dependent promises: Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError)Cannot access the second promise before initialization

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I try to handle dependent promises with axios in the client.

```
const App=()=>{
     useEffect(()=>{
             onTermSubmit()
       },[])
 
     const onTermSubmit=async(term)=>{
       if (term) {
        const responseLongLat = await opencage.get(
                    `/geocode/v1/json/?q=${term}&key=myKey` 
                 //This makes a request to opencage API and return a object with 
                 // longitud and latitude
                        );
          
       console.log(responseLongLat.data.results[0].geometry);//{lat: 52.5170365, lng: 13.3888599}

        const responseWeather = await darksky.get(
            `/forecast/myKey/${responseLongLat.lat},${responseLongLat.lng}`
                // This makes a resquest to DarkSky API and return a object with 
                // weather data
           );
         console.log(responseWeather.data.daily);//{summary: "Rain on Thursday through next Saturday.", icon: "rain", data: Array(8)} if hardcoded lat, long; otherwise error

      };

        return (
               <div>
                   <SearchBar onFormSubmit={onTermSubmit} />
               </div>
          )
 }
```

First I got a CORS policy error that I think I overcome prepending https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com to the main domain of DarkSky. And if I hardcode the latitude and longitud with particular data (e.j: 52.5170365,  13.3888599)it works and I got my weather data for that long, lat.

But if I put the variables in the literal string of the request to DarkSky derived from responseLongLat (*${responseLongLat.lat}*,*${responseLongLat.lng}*) I got the following error:
**Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): Cannot access 'responseWeather' before initialization**

Comment: In the code you posted, you are never accessing `responseWeather` anywhere.

Comment: I console.log the resuls of both requests to check. I updated the code with those console.logs and put their results

Answer (score 0):

You can only use await in an async function. Try this

```
async function getWeatherData(term) {
 const responseLongLat = await opencage.get(
`/geocode/v1/json/?q=${term}&key=myKey` 
  //This makes a request to opencage API and return a object with 
  // longitud and latitude
  );

console.log(responseLongLat.data.results[0].geometry);//{lat: 52.5170365, lng: 
13.3888599}

const responseWeather = await darksky.get(
 '/forecast/myKey/52.5170365,13.3888599'
 // This makes a resquest to DarkSky API and return a object with 
 // weather data
);

console.log(responseWeather.data.daily);

}

if(term) {
    getWeatherData(term);
}
```

Comment: I put the complete function with the async keyword. The function is within a component in a React application and need to take a parameter: term.                                                      The parameter is passed from another component, wich is the form where the user introduces the city (term) and submit passing the term submitted as a prop to the main component where is the above function. So, we need that parameter in the function.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for following my code. Actually I am using hooks and more in particular useEffect hook to retrieve the APIs.                                                                              So, the prop passing to the SearchBar component reference onTermSubmit, but this async func is within the useEffect hook. Should I pass the term to the main function in the hook?

Comment: You should put the function outside the useEffect hook. Then call it from within the hook.

Comment: Yes, that is what I already did it as indicated in my updated code. The only thing, as the term coming from the search bar is passed to the parameter in the async func, the conditional should be within that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution were, instead of passing the properties of the returned object in the first API call straight to the literal template of the second API call, we need to store them in two separate variables. Those variables are what we pass to the literal template.

```
 const responseLongLat = await opencage.get(
                `/geocode/v1/json/?q=${term}&key=myKey`)

 let responseWeatherLat = responseLongLat.data.results[0].geometry.lat;
 let responseWeatherLng = responseLongLat.data.results[0].geometry.lng;

 const responseWeather = await darksky.get(
 `/forecast/2623794cbf06a05c50f681a0869ab7ab/${responseWeatherLat},${responseWeatherLng}`
  );
```